# Wrapping a Class' subclass method

Tags: python, mongodb, class, generics

My main class is defined as follows:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from credentials import MongoMarketPlaceAuth


client = MongoClient('mongodb://conn_url:conn_port/', ssl=True)
db_connection = client.DB_NAME
db_connection.authenticate(name=MongoMarketPlaceAuth.name, password=MongoMarketPlaceAuth.password)
MarketPlace = db_connection


class MarketPlaceObjects(object):

    def __init__(self, collection, fields={}, default_filter={}):
        self.collection_name = collection
        self.fields = fields
        self.default_filter = default_filter
        if MarketPlace[collection].count() == 0:
            raise Exception('Collection does not exist or has zero objects')
        self.objects = MarketPlace[collection]
```

I then have a class that inherits my main class:

```
class Products(MarketPlaceObjects):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Products, self).__init__(collection='FlatProduct')
```

When used like so:

```
from products import Products
p = Products()
p.objects.find_one()
```

A dictionary is returned that describes all aspects of the product. 
What I would like to do is figure out is how

```
p.objects.find_one()
```

instead of returning a dictionary or a list of dictionaries it can return either one Product object (from a single returned dictionary) or a list of Product objects (from a returned list of dictionaries).

I'm having a hard time since I'm unsure how to I can wrap the find_one() or find() methods of PyMongo's collection class with my own Product class.

---

**UPDATE (2017-07-25):** 
This is what I ended up doing. Still needs some optimization:

Generic classes for the marketplace:

```
class CollectionObjectInstance(object):
    def __init__(self, response):
        for key, value in response.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                self.__dict__[key] = CollectionObjectInstance(value)
            else:
                self.__dict__[key] = value


class CollectionObjectsManager(object):

    serializer = CollectionObjectInstance
    collection = None
    default_projection = {}
    default_filter = {}

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__ = kwargs

    def find(self, filter={}, projection={}):
        filter = self.default_filter.update(filter)
        projection = self.default_projection.update(projection)
        res = self.collection.find(filter, projection)
        for o in res:
            yield self.serializer(o)

    def find_one(self, filter={}, projection={}):
        filter = self.default_filter.update(filter)
        projection = self.default_projection.update(projection)
        res = self.collection.find_one(filter, projection)
        return self.serializer(res)


class MarketPlaceCollection(object):

    collection_name = None
    serializer = None
    objects_manager = CollectionObjectsManager

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.collection_name is None:
            raise Exception('collection_name must be defined in class')
        if self.serializer is None:
            raise Exception('serializer must be defined in class')
        collection = MarketPlace[self.collection_name]
        if collection.count() == 0:
            raise Exception('Collection does not exist or has zero objects')
        self.collection = collection
        self.objects = self.objects_manager(**self.__dict__, **self.__class__.__dict__)
```

Product implementation using inheritance:

```
from marketplace import MarketPlaceCollection, CollectionObjectInstance
from settings import BASE_URL


URL_SUFFIX = 'product/'
CASH_PRICE_FEE = 50
LEASE_TERM_WEEKS = 52


class Product(CollectionObjectInstance):

    def url(self):
        url = BASE_URL + URL_SUFFIX + self.slug
        return url


class Products(MarketPlaceCollection):

    collection_name = 'FlatProduct'
    serializer = Product
```

Comment: besides your question, there is a common error in Python begginers in your code: you should not use mutable objects like `{}` as default arguments to functions or methods. That is because these dictioanaries are created  when the module is loaded, and re-used on every call to that function or method. Use  `None` as the default value and an `if` statement inside the method body to assign the parameter to an empty dict instead.

Comment: True! I try to avoid ifs because I figured it ads overhead. Do you think the performance is better by using the if and then assigning the empty dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `p.objects` you get the collection list itself,as attributed on the line `self.objects = MarketPlace[collection]`. Your `Products`   have no control over methods or attributes inside the `.objects` attribute anymore - it is an object as returned by pymongo.

So, to have control over methods and attributes of `Products.objects`, you have to create another class, with your desired methods, and return an object of that class when one tries to retrieve `Products.objects`.

Although Python has the  "property" decorator and the descriptor protocol, and a more sophisticated automation of your `objects` attribute could make use of them, in this case it can be made in a very straightforward way. Just have another class that receives the collection, and proxies the other attributes to the collection, by implementing `__getattr__` in it:

```
class ObjectList(object):
    def __init__(self, collection, cls):
        self.collection = collection
        self.cls = cls

    def find_one(self, *args, **kw):
        raw_list = self.collection.find_one(*arg, **kw)
        objects = [self.cls(**obj) for obj in raw_list]
        return objects[0] if len(objects) == 1 else objects

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        """this is called automatically by Python when a
           normal attribute is not found  in this object
        """ 
        return getattr(self.collection, attr)


class MarketPlaceObjects(object):

    def __init__(self, collection, cls, fields=None, default_filter=None):
        self.collection_name = collection
        self.fields = fields if fields else {}
        self.default_filter = default_filter if defaut_filter else {}
        if MarketPlace[collection].count() == 0:
            raise Exception('Collection does not exist or has zero objects')
        self.objects = ObjectList(MarketPlace[collection], cls)

class Products(MarketPlaceObjects):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Products, self).__init__(collection='FlatProduct', cls=Product)
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up coding up a solution before I saw your answer. However, I'm definitely going to be rewriting my code to take in some of the techniques you've used. My code currently looks non-pythonic haha.